# How to reuse Spring Cloud Gateway Docker image for multiple/different projects?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a `Spring Cloud` project with `Gateway`, `Config`, `discovery` and more than 20 microservices.
Whole project is Dockerized. Most of these microservices are reusable and we can use them as a docker image referenced from `docker-compose.yml` file in another projects.
I want to make `Spring Cloud Gateway` reusable too.
The problem here is that each project has a different set of routes and predicates. Is there a way to somehow `inject` route configuration in gateway's docker image definition?

Comment: It's just a spring boot application. Boot can reference external properties. So, maybe mount a volume with an external properties or yaml file?

Comment: Is it ok to use a config server for this purpose?

Comment: Yes it is valid to use config server